# get data from realtime database firebase throw function

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I'm building a  Cloud Functions  send notification that get the user id from realtime database and send a notification to a specifique device with his token .
the probleme that i could'nt get the user id and the token from firebase realTime database

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp();
exports.sendAdminNotification = 
functions.database.ref('/types/{userId}/token').onWrite((change, context) => {
const userId = context.params.val
const token = change.before.val()
console.log("data",token)

const payload = {
    data: {
         data_type: "direct_message",
         title: "Alert" ,
         message: "your animal is out of the zone please check him",
         message_id: "2",

        }
    };
return admin.messaging().sendToDevice(token, payload)
```

});

Comment: Answer to your first question is below. For the second question, we'll need to know two pieces of additional information: 1) how do you trigger this Cloud Function? As in: what operation on the database should result in a notification being sent? 2) What does the JSON under `/types/{userId}/token` look like. Please add a representative snippet of JSON to your question (as text, no screenshots please). You can get this by clicking the "Export JSON" link in the overflow menu (⠇) on your [Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data).

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to read the user ID from the path of the data being written with this code:

```
functions.database.ref('/types/{userId}/token').onWrite((change, context) => {
  const userId = context.params.val
```

To get a parameter from the path, you need to use `context.path.theNameOfTheParameter`. So in your case that'd be `context.params.userId`.